# C++ one-line string builder class

Tags: c++

**In short:** On one line of C++ code I want to stream strings and assign the stream content to a string variable:

```
int    i = 1;
double d = 3.2;

std::string str = StringBuilder() << "i=" << i << " and d=" << d;
```

- Can this be done?
- How is the implementation of class `StringBuilder`?
- How can `std::string` be expanded to accept the assignment from `StringBuilder`?
- Is it practical?

Comment: Yes, hint see: `std::string_stream`  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: You'll just need to provide `StringBuilder::operator<<` and `StringBuilder::operator std::string`.

Comment: "Can this be done?" - Yes. "How is the implementation of class StringBuilder?" - That's for you to figure out. "How can std::string be expanded to accept the assignment from StringBuilder?" - You can add template specialisations. "Is it practical?" - I don't see why not.   In the future; please stick to *one* question per SO question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom `StringBuilder` class, the STL already has its own built-in class - [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).  It is little tricky to use it in a 1-liner, but it can be done:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int    i = 1;
double d = 3.2;

std::string str = static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "i=" << i << " and d=" << d).str();
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/3UI7nz)

The `static_cast` is needed because the standard `operator<<` returns a `std::ostream&`, but `str()` is not a member of `std:::ostream`, only of `std::ostringstream`.  Since we know the `std::ostream&` refers to a `std::ostringstream` object, can can safely cast to it.

Normally, you would use a variable instead:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "i=" << i << " and d=" << d;
std::string str = oss.str();
```

---

But, let's say, for the sake of argument, that you did want to create a custom `StringBuilder` class.  It would simply need to implement `operator<<`, and a way to get the collected data in `std::string` format.  For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class StringBuilder
{
private:
    // this is just an example, you can use whatever you want
    // to collect and store the built data inside this class.
    // However, if you don't use std::ostringstream for the
    // collection, you may have to overload 'operator<<' for
    // every data type you want to support for input.  This
    // example uses a single templated override for simplicity...

    std::ostringstream m_strm;

public:
    template<typename T>
    StringBuilder& operator<<(const T &arg)
    {
        m_strm << arg;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return m_strm.str();
    }
};
```

```
#include <string>

int    i = 1;
double d = 3.2;

std::string str = StringBuilder() << "i=" << i << " and d=" << d;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ZgFJhw)

Comment: well this works for simple setups. Unfortunately for full functionality you need to add some `operator<<`. For instance  `StringBuilder() << std::endl` won't work as it is.

Comment: @bolov: True, you would need something like `StringBuilder& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&)) { m_strm << func; return *this; }` to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach: Make a function instead.

```
namespace impl
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    const std::stringstream::fmtflags stdfmt = ss.flags();
}

template <typename ...P> std::string make_str(const P &... params)
{
    impl::ss.clear();
    impl::ss.str("");
    impl::ss.flags(impl::stdfmt);
    (impl::ss << ... << params);
    return impl::ss.str();
}
```

---

```
int    i = 1;
double d = 3.2;

std::string str = make_str("i=", i, " and d=", d);
```

Comment: If you're doing this, note that [`absl::StrCat`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings#abslstrcat) does exactly this operation (at least for built in types or standard types) in a more efficient way (it's possible to avoid some allocations)